# How to force a keyboard to popup?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard

Is there a way how to force a keyboard to popup on Windows 10 Mobile? I have encountered a situation when I am in an input field (cursor is blinking) and a keyboard does not show up.

Comment: i get that issue in edge, clicking on website link bar and then on input field proved to be helpful most of the times.

Comment: @RamRaj I encountered this problem in an app, not Egde...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a bug in Windows 10 Mobile. You can try to click elsewhere in app and then click on the input field again and if it still doesn't work, try to reboot your phone or maybe restart the app itself.

Comment: Actually rebooting the phone helped in my case. But I am still curious whether there is a possibility to force a keyboard to pop up in case it does not show up. (Or isn't there such an option since this is a buggy situation that should not happen at all?)

Comment: I think you cant really force it to popup because it happened to me a couple of times while using Edge but it worked after launching the Edge again or sometimes after doing repeated clicks on `AddressBar`.